# How to get the image as background using url, with PHP, GD?

Tags: php, zend-framework, gd

I am trying to get image from one IP camera, which has url like http://publicip:1234/mypicture.jpeg

But how do i attache that image to this as background?

```
  $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://publicip/video/meandmyCPU.jpeg');
  //$black = imagecolorallocate($im,255,0,0);
  //              s   x  y
  Imagestring($im,19,70,70,'MY NAME IS!',$black);      
  header('Content-type: image/png');
  imagejpeg($im);
  imagedestroy($im);
```

But it does not show my texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you explicitly loading a font using imageloadfont?   I don't think 19 is a valid font identifier, unless you loaded it yourself, and given the docs on imageloadfont, I don't think 19 would be a valid identifier either.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php

If so, check that the load succeed, you don't have errors, etc.  Assuming it's the text not displaying (your question is somewhat unclear in that it asks about attaching a background, and also says the text doesn't appear, which implies that the image does)

If the background isn't appearing, check that you can actually open a URL over HTTP - the default config on my webhost disables it as it's a security risk (as one could use it to read in arbitrary data and possible execute it, if for instance, if there's a security hole).